# How to setup rule in Magento: Buy 1 "Hammer" and get FREE "Gloves"?

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules

Just like description specifies.
How to set up rules in Magento:
If you buy ONE Hammer you get a ONE pair FREE of XBRAND gloves (added to your cart automatically).

If someone buys TWO hammers, they get TWO pair FREE of XBRAND gloves.
If someone buys THREE hammers, they get THREE pair FREE of XBRAND gloves.

Please help me out ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you need an extension or code sample? As it not possible by default (

Comment: hmmm, really, please provide extension?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such standard-functionality in Magento.

Depending on WHEN you want to add the free items, you can use an observer that listens to the following events:

- `sales_convert_quote_to_order`: adding free item Y to the order, after customer placed his order. Item Y will not show up in cart before.
- `sales_quote_add_item` and `sales_quote_remove_item`: add/remove free item Y to/from cart when product X is added

In your observer methods, check if product X (hammer) is added and if so, add produt Y (gloves).